# SQL statement to find the last promotion date

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Some help will be greatly appreciated. I am trying to find the last date of most recent promotion of all employees from a dataset. A sample of the dataset is as below.
DATASET -

```
mysql> select * from emp;

+----+-------+-----------+------------+
| id | empid | title     | startdate  |
+----+-------+-----------+------------+
|  1 |   111 | Associate | 2017-11-01 |
|  2 |   222 | ED        | 2017-11-01 |
|  3 |   111 | Associate | 2017-12-01 |
|  4 |   222 | MD        | 2017-12-01 |
|  5 |   111 | VP        | 2018-01-01 |
|  6 |   222 | MD        | 2018-01-01 |
|  7 |   111 | VP        | 2018-02-01 |
|  8 |   222 | MD        | 2018-02-01 |
+----+-------+-----------+------------+
```

The output I want -

```
+-------+-----------+----------------+
| empid | title     | min(startdate) |
+-------+-----------+----------------+
|   222 | MD        | 2017-12-01     |
|   111 | VP        | 2018-01-01     |
+-------+-----------+----------------+
```

I tried this SQL -

```
mysql> select empid, title, min(startdate) 
       from ( select * from emp ) x 
       group by title, empid 
       order by empid desc;
```

It outputs all groups, like this -

```
+-------+-----------+----------------+
| empid | title     | min(startdate) |
+-------+-----------+----------------+
|   222 | MD        | 2017-12-01     |
|   222 | ED        | 2017-11-01     |
|   111 | Associate | 2017-11-01     |
|   111 | VP        | 2018-01-01     |
+-------+-----------+----------------+
```

Comment: Hint:  `group by empid`.  Period.

Answer (score 0):

Take the empid  and the max(startdate) ONLY, as a subquery and join it back to the main table:

```
SELECT *
FROM emp e
  INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT empid, Max(startdate) recentpromo FROM emp GROUP BY empid) x
  ON x.empid = e.empid AND x.recentpromo = e.startdate
```

If you're on mysql8 you could use ROW_NUMBER for this as an alternative. If an employee is promoted twice on the same day this will pick up both records, though I think that unlikely to occur

Edit, so we can extend this another level:

```
SELECT
  em.empid,
  em.title,
  min(em.startdate) as

FROM
  emp em
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT e.empid, e.title
    FROM emp e
      INNER JOIN 
      (SELECT empid, Max(startdate) recentpromo FROM emp GROUP BY empid) x
      ON x.empid = e.empid AND x.recentpromo = e.startdate
  ) frpt --find recent promo title
  ON 
    em.empid = frpt.empid AND
    em.title = frpt.title
GROUP BY
  em.empid, em.title
```

Comment: no it gives me the last day of the recent promo. I want the first day of the recent promotion. I tried MIN function, but no luck.

Comment: You can't swap it for MiN, you can however use the logic to find the most recent promo, then join it to the emp table to find the title of that promo, then join THAT to emp again to find all the occurrences of that title and THEN you can group/min them

Answer (score 0):

You can filter on the latest title per employee with a correlated subquery, and then aggregate:

```
select empid, title, min(startdate)
from emp e
where e.title = (
    select e1.title 
    from emp e1 
    where e1.empid = e.empid 
    order by startdate desc 
    limit 1
)
group by empid, title
order by empid desc
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ab0d1fbf524477b0b8532142c447cb6e)**:

```
empid | title | min(startdate)
----: | :---- | :-------------
  222 | MD    | 2017-12-01    
  111 | VP    | 2018-01-01
```